# How to inject a declarative service my JvmModelInferrer

Tags: eclipse, xtext, declarative-services

I have an xtext project which contains MyDslJvmModelInferrer. 
In this inferrer I would like to use my declarative service, which is defined like described in [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGiServices/article.html), and process the parsed model within the service.

How can I get access to the declarative service within my ModelInferrer?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a instance binding and then use the default api code as described in the tutorial

```
def void configureMyService(Binder binder) {
    val BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext(); 
    val ServiceReference<?> serviceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference(IMyService.getName());
    val IMyService service = bundleContext.getService(serviceReference) as IMyService; 
    binder.bind(IMyService).toInstance(service)
}
```

then a normal `@Inject IMyService myService` should work

update: i dont know when the osgi services will be available so you may have to do this lazy

in the module

```
import com.google.inject.Provider
...
def Provider<IMyService> provideIMyService() {
    return new MyServiceProvider
}
```

create the provider class

```
import com.google.inject.Provider
class MyServiceProvider implements Provider<IMyService> {

    override get() {
        val BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext(); 
        val ServiceReference<?> serviceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference(IMyService.getName());
        val IMyService service = bundleContext.getService(serviceReference) as IMyService; 
        return service
    }

}
```

and use it
    import com.google.inject.Provider
    ...
    @Inject Provider myServiceProvider
    ... // inside method
    val myService = myServiceProvider.get

Comment: Ok, and where do I have to put this method? I'm a bit clueless.

Comment: to the runtime or ui module (runtimemodule has no osgi available) i dont know if you ever call your code standalone with no osgi envionment

Comment: I guess, for the moment within an eclipse environment is enought. Tried it in MyDslRuntimeModule.java an MyDslUiModule.java. Both weren't successful.

Comment: what is the error you get? did you debug the cofigure method? maybe the osgi services are not created yet and you need to inject and call a MyServiceProider instead? i will add some dummy code for that as well

Comment: I createt MyServiceProvider, the method provideMyService in MyDslUiModule.java, but it seems, this method isn't called. I tested it with an simple println.
But my service has to be awailible. I use it in another project, which is running at the same time.
Error like this are in the console:
No implementation for MyService was bound.
  while locating com.google.inject.Provider<MyService>
    for field at MyDslJvmModelInferrer.lpServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.xtext.service.MethodBasedModule.configure(MethodBasedModule.java:57)

Comment: make sure you use import com.google.inject.Provider and not import javax.inject.Provider (i have filed https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=485263 on that)

Comment: Hm, I created a new project in another workspace and tried the steps you described in the bug (but using com.google.inject). Then I imported my service plugins and tried the configureMyService method of your first answer and it worked. Maybe I broke my projects at the first time I tried some stuff. Or it's because I used xtext 2.8.x, I forgot to mention. Just a little question (yes org no). Is it possible to inject classes like JvmTypesBuilder, which is used in my generator, in a declared service? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: sry i am not that deep into osgi declarative services but maybe you can pass it as parameter instead